# Inspect object with JS

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to inspect an element with JavaScript as it does a FireBug or DevTool? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: If I interpret your question correctly, I think when inspecting an element, Javascript will be executed and the result will be rendered. If you view the page source, you will only see the script itself.

Comment: Press Ctrl / Cmd + Shift + C and select the element you want to inspect then go to `Properties` tab next to `Style`, `Computed` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate that using javascript, with the exception of inspecting pseudo-elements created from pseudo-classes like `:after`.

All that is showing is the element's tagName, id, classList, and dimensions, which are all available through the element's properties and computed style properties;

```
var tag = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
var id = element.id;
var classes = element.classList.toString();
var width = window.getComputedStyle( element ).width;
var height = window.getComputedStyle( element ).height;
```

Demo, not the best but illustrates its use

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  var element = e.target;
  var tag = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
  var id = element.id ? "#"+element.id:"";
  var classes = element.classList.toString().replace(/\s/, ".");
  classes = classes ? "."+classes:"";
  var width = window.getComputedStyle(element).width;
  var height = window.getComputedStyle(element).height;
  element.setAttribute("data-tooltip", `${tag}${id}${classes} ${width} x ${height}`);
});
```

```css
* {
  position: relative;
}

*:not(body):not(html):hover:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding:6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2">
  This is some text
  <table id="table" class="someclass">
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1">Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 6</td>
      <td>Data 5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly I need!